# JSON ValueError: Expecting , delimiter

Tags: python, json

`json.loads(res)` where `res` is response from a url getting following error

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter:
```

on replacing '\n' by '\n' getting error -

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

what should be done ?

Comment: Can you post full json to here?

Comment: Sounds like your JSON is invalid.  Specifically, it's expecting a `,` but finding something else.

Comment: link for json i'm getting: https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/14086281/posts?maxResults=20&pageToken=CgkIFBjh84yboyIQieHbBg&key=AIzaSyAmyeU6OLAyBXDt7M9A83_YdnGqfoe_dak

Comment: i have validated it using JSON lint, it shows it to be a valid json

Comment: don't put additional info about your question in the comments, [edit] your question instead

Answer (score 2):

[The url that you've provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192211/json-valueerror-expecting-delimiter/23194787#comment35472924_23192211) returns a valid json. Either it was a temporary error or your code corrupts the response so it is no longer a valid json.

To load a json from an url using stdlib:

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'https://example.com/get/json'
data = json.load(urlopen(url))
```

Comment: `from urllib2 import urlopen`-
this is the handiest tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import pycurl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
import cStringIO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

buf = cStringIO.StringIO()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

c=pycurl.Curl()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/14086281/posts?maxResults=20&pageToken=CgkIFBjh84yboyIQieHbBg&key=AIzaSyAmyeU6OLAyBXDt7M9A83_YdnGqfoe_dak')                                                                                                         
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
c.perform()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

js=json.loads( buf.getvalue() )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
print js
```